# vagrant up fails with: cannot translate name @ rb_sysopen when trying to run homestead

Tags: powershell, homestead, wsl-2, vagrant-windows

When I run `vagrant up` I get the following error:

```sh
Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.14/gems/vagrant-2.2.14/plugins/hosts/suse/host.rb:20:in `initialize': Cannot translate name. @ rb_sysopen - /etc/os-release (Errno::ELOOP)
```

I have installed Vagrant for Windows and I'm trying to launch Laravel's Homestead that I cloned in WSL2 by cd'ing into the `Z:` directory that WSL2 provides via PowerShell (so that I have access to Vagrant that's installed on Windows).

```sh
cd Z:\home\coder\projects\homestead
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that Vagrant is trying to recognize the OS from the filesystem if I'm understanding correctly. So if you're trying to run Vagrant on Windows across a network share that is Unix/WSL/Linux it seems that it will try to run as if it is Unix and fail.

### Solution

I was able to copy the `homestead` directory from the network share into my Windows environment and then navigate to that directory and run `vagrant up` successfully using powershell.

### Another Option

It sounds like you should also be able to install Vagrant within WSL2 and use it from within WSL2 instead of PowerShell.

Another possibility to note is that you can invoke exes from within WSL2, but it sounds like it will not work properly if you were trying to run Window's Vagrant from within WSL2.

### Research

- https://github.com/roots/trellis/issues/1083
- https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/other/wsl.html
- https://discourse.roots.io/t/command-vagrant-up-in-wsl-is-failed/16528